# Specifying gcc output file name in a bash alias

Tags: c, bash, gcc

I have begun learning C using ncurses and would like to make the compile command a bit less long winded to type out. The following is the full command I'm using.

```
gcc example.c -o example -lncurses
```

What I would like to do is make a bash alias that fulfills the above but only having to type, say...

```
gcc_alias example.c
```

I don't have much experience with bash at all but is it possible to make a little one-line alias in my .bashrc to accomplish this?

I've tried on my own and the best I can come up with is:

```
gcc_alias="gcc $1 -o ____ -lncurses"
```

Where obviously ____ is the part that I can't figure out.

I've looked for answers but haven't been able to find a similar enough problem.
Cheers.

Comment: arg... aliases can't take arguments. Read about `functions`. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot be done with an alias (aliases are strictly text replacement). You can use a shell function like this:

```
gcc_alias() { gcc -o "${1%.*}" "$1" -lncurses; }
```

to be called as

```
gcc_alias example.c
```

Here `${1%.*}` is a parameter expansion that removes the shortest suffix matching `.*` from `$1`.

Seriously though, to make compilation manageable, you'll want to take a look at [makefiles](http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/).

Comment: You beat me to it, I was going to suggest the same thing. I never know what to call these, since some people refer to them as `functions`, `shortcuts`, `helpers`, etc. You might want to include that this could be placed within `.bash_profile` too.

Comment: The bash manpage calls them "shell functions", so I usually go with that. POSIX also uses the term "function," but I had to look that up.

Comment: Thanks @Wintermute for both answering the question and providing the better alternative. I'll look into makefiles.